# Configure a startup URL for an Apple TV

Tags: apple-tv

I would like to configure an Apple TV so that every time it starts it should open a browser with a specific URL.
The usecase would be something like: If the TV is on but not used it should display some company information web page.

Is this possible and if it is can anyone please explain how?
I would like to do this without the need to develop an application or do any programing, just by using the existing features of an Apple TV.

Thanks,
Mihai

Comment: There's no Safari on the Apple TV, so I doubt it's possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

I also asked this on the Apple community forums and got the response there
https://discussions.apple.com/message/31634122?ac_cid=op123456#31634122

Indeed it is not possible with Apple TV 4.